# Custom error handler with __PRETTY_FUNCTION__

Tags: c++

I was trying to build my own error handler that throws errors depending on the some error numbers that i have implimented in an enum class errorNo{}. I also wanted to include the source function using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. The error handler looks like this (less complicated version ... with std::string ... without errorNo from the enum):

> void errorHandler(std::string message, int errorCode){
>      switch (errorCode){
>      default:
>      throw std::runntime_error(message);
>   }
>   }

Then call it like:

> errorHandler(std::string("Error in: ")+`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, 0);

Is there a way for the errorhandler to automatically get the function name in which it was called without any explicit declaration? I tried:

> void errorHandler(std::string message, int errorCode , const char* functionName = `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`){
>
> throw std::runntime_error(message + " in " + functionName)
>
> }

I get a warning that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is only allowed in function and even after i get an ouput, i get the 'error in top level'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in a `std::string` in that particular function and then pass that string to `errorHandler` function.

Something like this:

```
void foo()
{
    std::string message, funcName;
    message = "Error";
    funcName = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    errorHandler(message, 0 , funcName);
}
```

See live demo [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9aa700a0d0413a6).